Adding Access Token Management to HttpClient seemingly does not work
I'm trying to add access token management to my httpClient. I have a method that adds autogenerated api clients to the service collection with TInterface and TImplementation as the service descriptors. During this process I also create a named token management client to link the token management client to the named http client that is registered after.
Here's the code:
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        
// This is the unique name for the httpClient
var clientUniqueName = $"{clientName}-{Guid.NewGuid()}";

// This is the unique name for the client registered to token management
var tokenClientName = $"client.{clientUniqueName}";

credentialsBuilder.AddClient(tokenClientName, client =>
{
    client.TokenEndpoint = clientAuthConfig.TokenEndpoint;
    client.ClientId = clientAuthConfig.ClientId;
    client.ClientSecret = clientAuthConfig.ClientSecret;

    client.Scope = $"lns:{clientName}";
});

services.AddClientCredentialsHttpClient(clientUniqueName, tokenClientName, client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
});

services.AddSingleton(typeof(TInterface), provider =>
{
    var httpClientFactory = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
    var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(clientUniqueName);
    return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TImplementation), httpClient, baseAddress)!;
});

The issue is that seemingly no token authentication is happening. All the configs such as ClientId, Secret, Scope etc are correct and fills out, and when I try to make a call using the registered client, the baseAddress used is the correct one from the config which indicates that it is using the correct HttpClient registered in the method above.
Is there something I'm missing? I've used the following as my example:
https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/Duende.AccessTokenManagement/wiki/worker-applications

The implementation above was in fact correct and it was actually the token endpoint that threw back a 403, which I thought was coming from the actual API I was trying to call. I assumed no token management was being done because of this.
